# C# code equivalent for Applying RowValidationRules on DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, datagrid

We can apply RowValidationRules on a DataGrid by using following XAML.

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
  <local:MyValidationClass ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

I want to know how can I achieve same through C# Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
grid.RowValidationRules.Add(new CourseValidationRule() { 
                ValidationStep = ValidationStep.UpdatedValue 
            });
```

Note that you need to set the ValidationStep.